# CMake's ctest: image not found (possible rpath issue)

Tags: c++, macos, unix, build, cmake

A CMake project builds and runs tests OK on Linux and Windows, but running the test program fails on macOS.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libfoo.dylib
  Referenced from: /some/path/test_foo
  Reason: image not found
```

I can verify that `libfoo.dylib` is in the same dir as the test program `test_foo`. Running `./test_foo` works OK.

CMake calls `test_foo` via `ctest` (located in another path). Calling by `ctest` seems to be what makes it fail, but if I try a command like this (working dir being `/some/path`) it works:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` /another/path/ctest
```

I assume that running tests with `add_test` and `ctest` without setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is possible since I can just run `test_foo` with success, but I haven't had luck.

Here are the current relevant contents of CMakeLists.txt

```
set(TEST_LIBS foo)
set(TEST_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(test_foo tests/testfoo.cpp)

set_target_properties(test_foo PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DSELF_TEST")
target_link_libraries(test_foo ${TEST_LIBS} ${STUFF})
add_dependencies(build_tests test_foo)

add_test(NAME test_foo COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:test_foo>
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TEST_DIR})
```

- I've tried setting/unsetting `CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH` and `MACOSX_RPATH` before these lines, as suggested [here](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Absolute-Path-linking-library-td7585352.html):
- I've tried adding the following snippet after the lines, as suggested [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-April/043826.html):

  ```
   IF(APPLE)
       SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR ${TEST_DIR})
       SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH ON)
   ENDIF(APPLE)
  ```
- I've not tried [using `install`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling), I'm not sure how to configure that for my project or even what it does.

Any known approaches or any obvious mistakes here? Is `install` worth looking at? I want to be able to run the test from the CMake generated `ctest` line in the Makefile.

CMake 3.5.2, macOS 10.12.5

Comment: What CMake version does your project set in its call to `cmake_minimum_required()`? This command does more than just setting the minimum CMake version, it also sets CMake's behaviour to match that version as well. Are you specifying an older version by chance (i.e. < 3.0)? Probably not your issue here, but something to try for now.

Comment: `I can verify that 'libfoo.dylib' is in the same dir as the test program 'test_foo'.` - Really? Your executable is created under **binary** tree, do you have the library there? If so, why do you use `TEST_DIR` as working directory or as a RPATH, while it points to **source** tree (`tests` subdirectory)?

Comment: @CraigScott I'll try that tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Tsyvarev Both libfoo.dylib and test_foo are in the same dir, that I can say. I didn't create the cmake file, I think that, for debugging purposes, some source files are copied to the binary tree, but yes, the source tree is elsewhere. It'll be good for me to understand this process better, I'll verify this tomorrow once I have access to the Mac.

Comment: @CraigScott Though I did have a cmake_minimum_version for 2.6, changing that to 3.5 didn't seem to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You're right, that was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as mentioned in comments, thanks to @Tsyvarev

Original comment pointing to the cause of the issue:

`I can verify that 'libfoo.dylib' is in the same dir as the test program 'test_foo'.` - Really? Your executable is created under binary tree, do you have the library there? If so, why do you use TEST_DIR as working directory or as a RPATH, while it points to source tree (tests subdirectory)?